# how to pass HTTP Header to Junit test case

Tags: junit, http-headers

How do i pass the HttpHeader object to the JUnit test case?

Now i'm writing the test case of my class.I want to pass the HttpHeader object parameter to my test case method to check whether the method is working or not. So any one give me the suggestion to that.

I have googled alot and wasted much time in getting the perfect way.
Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a class that implements the interface, or mock it using a framework like Mockito.